# Manual SIMD code affordability

Tags: c++, performance, x86, compiler-optimization, simd

We're running a project that is highly computationally intensive, and right now we're letting the compiler do SSE optimizations. However, we're not sure we are getting the best performance for the code.

My question is, I understand, broad, but I don't find many suggestions about this: is writing manual SIMD code **affordable**, or in other terms, worth the effort?

Affordability means, here, a rough estimate of cost benefit, as for instance `speedup / development_time`, or any other measure that is reasonable in the context of project development.

To lessen the scope:

- we profiled the code and we know the computation is the most heavy part
- we have a C++ code that can easily make use of Boost.SIMD and similar libraries
- affordability should not take care of code *readability*, we assume we're confident with SSE/AVX
- the code is currently multithreaded (OpenMP)
- our compiler is Intel's `icc`

Comment: _"My question is, I understand, broad ..."_ So why are you asking if you already know it's _off-topic_?

Comment: Have you considered parallelization (e.g. threads)? Perhaps only hand-optimize *part* of the code? Before you actually tried something and compared the results to some baseline it's really going to be hard for anyone so say anything specific.

Comment: You should probably specify your compiler. I know Intel considers vectorization a major advantage of ICC. When I gave GCC a try, on the other hand, it had minimal, fairly dated support. In general, I think compilers are more limited in their ability to apply SIMD than an experienced programmer in non-trivial scenarios. Have no idea if this applies to your case.

Comment: The term "affordability" is also much to broad on its own. Do you mean in man-hours? Perceived or actual speedups? Something else? Or perhaps a combination?

Comment: I clarified as much as I can your concerns. @Someprogrammerdude we don't have a baseline to compare with, except the code we have now. Since this is a design decision, we have to make some cost/benefit analysis, which we're not familiar with (for instance, knowing other project that actually did this SIMD porting).

Comment: If you have profiled the code sufficiently to identify a few functions that are the bottleneck, *and* you have reasonably competent assembly-language programmers, then it is *definitely* worth the effort. Manually optimizing one reasonably-scoped function would take a good programmer about a day's worth of effort, maybe two to ensure it is completely debugged. Even optimizing several functions would take no more than a week's worth of effort, and for a reasonable speedup, this seems like a good investment of time to me. What else could the developers do in a week that would add so much value?

Comment: A skilled programmer should also be able to look at the compiler's actual output, and in a matter of hours, determine whether a speed-up is reasonably possible by hand-optimizing the code and even estimate what percentage improvement you might be able to expect. This would allow you to make better informed decisions, instead of guessing, for a minimal cost investment. If you don't have anyone on staff who is skilled enough to do this, then you might hire a consultant. There are several of us here on SO that would probably be able to help. My email address can be found in my profile. :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quite agree with Paul R, and just wanted to add that IMO in most cases intrinsics/asm optimizations are not worth the effort. In most cases those optimizations are marketing driven, i.e. we juicing the performance on a specific platform just to get (in most cases) a bit better numbers.

Nowadays it is almost impossible to get an order of magnitude of performance just rewriting your C/C++ code in asm. In most cases it is a matter of memory/cache access and methods/algorithms (i.e. parallelization) as Paul has noted.

The first thing you should try is to analyze your code with hardware performance counters (with free "perf" tool or Intel VTune) and understand the real bottlenecks. For example, memory access during the computation is the most common bottleneck in fact, not computation itself. So manual vectorization of such a code does not help, since the CPU stalls on memory anyway.

Such analysis is always worth the effort, since you better understand your code and CPU architecture.

The next thing you should try is to optimize your code. There are a variety of methods: optimize data structures, cache-friendly memory access patterns, better algorithms etc. For example, an order you declare fields in a structure might have a significant performance impact in some cases, because you structure might have holes and occupy two lines of cache instead of one. Another example is false sharing, when you ping-pong same cache lines between CPUs and simple cache alignment might give you an order of magnitude better performance.

Those optimization are always worth the effort, since they will impact your low-level code as well.

Then you should try to help your compiler. For example, by default compiler vectorize/unroll an inner loop, but it might be better to vectorize/unroll an outer loop. You do this with #pragma hints and sometimes it worth the effort.

The last thing you should try is to rewrite already highly optimized C/C++ code using intrinsics/asm. There might be some reasons for that, such as better instructions interleave (so your CPU pipelines are always busy) or use of special CPU instructions (i.e. for encryption). The actual number of reasonable intrinsics/asm usages are negligible, and they are always platform-dependent.

So, with no further details about your code/algorithms it is hard to guess if it makes sense in your case, but I would bet for no. Better spend the effort on analysis and platform-independent optimizations. Better have a look on OpenCL or similar frameworks if you really need that computation power. At last, invest in better CPUs: the effect of such an investment is predictable and instantaneous.

Comment: Good point about the top-down nature of optimisation - get the design and the algorithms right first, then concentrate on data structures and cache/memory usage, before even starting on code optimisation and low level stuff like SIMD. Having said that, for "bleeding edge" performance you need to do all of the above, but in the general case you can get away with a lot less (including no optimisation at all!).

Comment: Massive speedups are certainly possible.  e.g. I got a factor of 50 speedup on Intel Skylake from manual use of C++ intrinsics for AVX+FMA for a function that checks an array of points for being inside/outside a polygon.  (The usual project-a-ray algo with 4 to 8 vertices, for an array of ~1M points, with the x and y coords stored in separate arrays.  The 50x speedup is vs. a scalar C++ implementation on the same Skylake CPU.  The initial vectorized version was 30x faster than scalar, and tweaking the source to get gcc to make good asm for HSW/SKL found another ~1.5x speedup.)

Comment: I don't think I could have written it in portable C++ in a way that gcc could auto-vectorize to code that was as good.  And even if I could have, it was easier to use intrinsics.  (Using Agner Fog's Vector Class Library, I was able to template it so I could easily make an AVX512 version that shares almost all the code with the AVX2 version.)  Of course, I'm a performance tuning expert, so I knew what asm I wanted the compiler to make.  Anyway, upvoted for pointing out that memory bandwidth is a big deal.  For things other than polygon (e.g. ellipse and rectangle), memory was a bottleneck.

Comment: @PeterCordes thanks for the comments. Just few notes: 1) I do agree that in some cases significant speedups are possible. Encryption is a good example IMO -- there are instructions for permutation/hash calculation on some platforms. Unfortunately, we have no code in hands, so those are just speculations... 2) IMO ICC is a different league in terms of vectorization in comparison with GCC, but it is not perfect and there is always a room for improvement...

Comment: @PeterCordes And 3) Moving from AVX2 to AVX-512 is one thing, but moving from Intel to ARM platform is another. Considering all the possibilities to increase the performance, one might find that investing in an ARM system (or a farm) with 100+ cores each would have a better bang for the buck. Just an example, sure it all depends on the tasks...

Comment: Yeah, I definitely had to give up portability to ARM to get that much speedup.  I don't think I could have done as well with portable GNU C vector extensions.  AFAIK, ARM doesn't even have a movemask instruction, so it can't easily turn a packed-compare into a bitmap, which is key for what I was doing.  And anyway, the goal here was lower end-to-end latency for interactive data-analysis, running on a Google Cloud VM.  (Thread-level parallelism and/or GPGPU is our next avenue of attack on the problem.)  Good suggestions for other use-cases, though.

Comment: I was going to ask the same question, until I found this one. I've been painfully trying to "optimize" with Neon assembly for some days, and it always ended up with worse performance. I'm not experienced in writing at instruction level, but even copying existing implementations didn't bring me any improvement. I seriously don't know how much room there is to improve when the compiler is already generating Neon instructions, and whether manual Neon is really working for other code bases. Are they just relics from when Neon just came out and the compilers weren't ready for it yet.

Answer (score 3):

You need to do a cost-benefit analysis, e.g. if you can invest say X months of effort at a cost of $Y getting your code to run N times faster, and that translates to either a reduction in hardware costs (e.g. fewer CPUs in an HPC context), or reduced run-time which in some way equates to a cost benefit, then it's a simple exercise in arithmetic. (Note however that there are some intangible long-term costs, e.g. SIMD-optimized code tends to be more complex, more error-prone, less portable, and harder to maintain.)

If the performance-critical part of your code (the hot 10%) is vectorizable then you may be able to get an order of magnitude speed-up (less for double precision float, more for narrower data types such as 16 bit fixed point).

Note that this kind of optimisation is not always just a simple matter of converting scalar code to SIMD code - you may have to think about your data structures and your cache/memory access pattern.

Comment: Yes, cost-benefit, but actually we don't know how to estimate these factors. We know that our computational part is taking 50-70% of the time, with floating point (or double) operations. If we had some previous clinical case we could have an insight, but we didn't find any source on these matters.

Comment: Well if you can add some more detail to your question I may be able to give you some hand-waving estimates. Ideally you would need to show an execution profile (collect using e.g. perf on Linux) and some code for the most performance-critical parts. You might also want to consider hiring a consultant to help you assess the project/provide mentoring/implement the SIMD code (in which case I am contactable via LinkedIn. ;-)).